# A sudoku that's already filled in for you

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

[image]

The usual rules of sudoku apply: each row and column must have one of each digit; plus, if you divide the whole nine-by-nine grid into nine three-by-three subgrids, then each subgrid has one of each digit. Special for this sudoku, though, some areas are heavily outlined; each of these must contain precisely the digits printed in it, with the same multiplicity.

---

By request, the blank grid:

[image]

Comment: Check out Penpa (https://swaroopg92.github.io/penpa-edit/). Works perfect for these type of puzzles.

Comment: Is there a reason why the answer has not been accepted?

Comment: @ACB it leaves us hanging midway.

Comment: [Penpa+ link](https://tinyurl.com/2pguht8p)

Answer (score 9):

This is my solution:

> [image: solution]

> My approach was fairly simple:
>  1. Note down the possible digits for each cell, according to the rules.
>  2. Solve it like a usual Sudoku.

Here are the basic steps:

> Put all the possible digits in the outlined areas according to the question:
>  [image]
>
>  Digits that appear multiple times inside one area and therefore must exist at a specific position:
>  [image]
>
>  Following the general Sudoku rules (specificly: unique digits in column, row and subgrids):
>  [image]
>
>  Some more deduction using the general Sudoku rules:
>  [image]
>
>  Continue to solve the Sudoku.

Comment: Could you provide any more detail for your solution path? Even just some key deductions with pictures would be nice. Solutions to [grid-deduction] questions are generally expected to explain their solution path.

Comment: @bobble Yes, I thought about that. But I actually did nothing more than draw a blank Sudoku, put all the possible digits in the outlined areas according to the question, and then solved the puzzle like a normal Sudoku.

Comment: Would it be possible to show any interesting steps, or even just several picture of intermediate states?

Comment: I coulda sworn I needed to use the heavily-outlined-area logic when solving. Guess not.

Comment: @bobble I added some steps, until it clearly can be solved like a normal Sudoku. Is this helpful?

Comment: Confirmed via constraint programming with 27 ALLDIFF and 18 GCC constraints.

Comment: @msh210 You are right, there was a step where I drew my conclusions from the digits occurring multiple times within an area.

Comment: @npkllr, yes this is better. Thank you for adding more explanation

Comment: The final answer is correct but I'm not sure I understand how you got it. For example, how did you get the 3 in row 3, column 7, in step 2?

Comment: @msh210 that 3 follows because the two 3s from the 3-3-5-6-8 region cover columns 8 and 9.

Comment: @RobPratt , oh, there are certainly ways to get at it, but the answer doesn't say how the answerer did so.

Comment: @RobPratt Man, I wish I had your optimization skillz in my toolkit. If you ever give an online class, please let me know :-)

Comment: @JeremyDover I added an answer that describes the constraint programming formulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via constraint programming as follows.  For each cell $(i,j)$, let integer decision variable $x_{i,j} \in [1,9]$ be the digit that appears in that cell.  The usual sudoku rules yield 27 ALLDIFF constraints, one per row, column, or 3-by-3 box.  For example,
the ALLDIFF constraint for row 1 is
$$\operatorname{ALLDIFF}(x_{1,1}, x_{1,2}, x_{1,3}, x_{1,4}, x_{1,5}, x_{1,6}, x_{1,7}, x_{1,8}, x_{1,9}),$$
the ALLDIFF constraint for column 1 is
$$\operatorname{ALLDIFF}(x_{1,1}, x_{2,1}, x_{3,1}, x_{4,1}, x_{5,1}, x_{6,1}, x_{7,1}, x_{8,1}, x_{9,1}),$$
and the ALLDIFF constraint for the top left 3-by-3 box is
$$\operatorname{ALLDIFF}(x_{1,1}, x_{1,2}, x_{1,3}, x_{2,1}, x_{2,2}, x_{2,3}, x_{3,1}, x_{3,2}, x_{3,3}).$$
For each of the 18 regions, there is also a global cardinality constraint (GCC).  For example, the central plus-shaped region requires
$$\operatorname{GCC}(x_{3,5}, x_{4,5}, x_{5,3}, x_{5,4}, x_{5,5}, x_{5,6}, x_{5,7}, x_{6,5}, x_{7,5}; \{(2,1,1), (3,1,1), (4,1,1), (5,1,1), (7,1,1), (8,2,2), (9,2,2)\}).$$  The interpretation is that the seven variables in the first argument must together take the values 2, 3, 4, 5, and 7 once each and the values 8 and 9 twice each.

Comment: I don't think a programming answer is helpful when the given puzzle is already shown to be solvable by hand with logic.

Comment: Hmm, I thought multiple approaches were encouraged.

Comment: @Bubbler I see your point, but this is not just "I wrote a python script". Rather it is a mathematical formulation that I appreciate learning more about.